# Restarting ASP.NET Core application takes longer sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating ASP NET Core 5.0 Web API and hosting it on Linux server (Ubuntu 18). I am also using service for my app according this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-5.0#create-the-service-file).

I noticed that when I restart the application sometimes it takes a long time to start. For monitoring, I log the moment the application is launched, and at the end I send an alert via Telegram Bot.

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try
            {              
                logger.Debug("Program starts");                            // Logging start

                var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
                using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
                {
                    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    var rootRepo = services.GetRequiredService<IRootRepository>();

                    await rootRepo.SendRestartMessage();                   //My alert

                    ...                  
                }
                await host.RunAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ...
            }
            finally
            {
                ...
            }          
        }
```

Sometimes a message appears in the logger that the program has started, but after that I need to wait ~5-20 minutes before other messages start to appear in the logger and a notification is received. For example:

```
2021-05-08 19:59:32.9757||DEBUG|App.Program|Program starts 
2021-05-08 20:18:25.3136|50|WARN|Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository|Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage. 
2021-05-08 20:18:25.3214|59|WARN|Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager|Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits. 
2021-05-08 20:18:26.4650|35|WARN|Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager|No XML encryptor configured. Key {..} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form. 
2021-05-08 20:18:26.6787||INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Now listening on: http://localhost:5000 
2021-05-08 20:18:26.6787||INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. 
2021-05-08 20:18:26.6787||INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Hosting environment: Production 
2021-05-08 20:18:26.6787||INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Content root path: /var/app
```

It seems to me that this happens once a day, another restart will take 30 seconds to fully start. The next day, the first restart again can take a long time.

*Added later.* I uploaded an absolutely identical application to the server, connected to an identical database, in which, unlike the main version, there is simply less data. I also have a folder with static files which I define as follows

```
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
         FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Files")),
         RequestPath = new PathString("/Files")
        });
```

In my `startup.cs`

So version fith empty `/Resources` folder always restart in 5-10 seconds.

Original app `/Resources` folder contains a lot of images and app still takes a lot of time(up to 20 minutes) for restart, and second restart for original app completes in 10 seconds.

Is it possible that my static files can cause this?

Comment: That's not a standard ASP.NET Core `Program.cs`, so likely all the bits you've omitted are causing the problem. What is stopping you from doing your own basic debugging to figure out what is hanging?

Comment: @IanKemp I doubt very much the code that called after I send myself a notification can slows it. I get it right after the following message appears in the logger after  `Program starts`. And i mentioned that I run it on server, so it happend only then

Comment: The only non-standard thing here is `rootRepo.SendRestartMessage()` and anything that happens in ... areas. So i would look into those calls. Just add more log message s, right before and right after any function call that might be a suspect. `UseStaticFiles` will not cause issues when you have a lot of files, because at this point it does nothing with the files, it just registeres a middleware class. The issue might not even be in your application, maybe it a service or database that you call responds very slowly

Comment: Check how resources files are copied. There is an options like, always copy, copy if newer etc. also important thing is where do you run that? In the docker or ? Azure app service?

Comment: @grinay I just run it on server like i mentioned in the beginning with kestrel and nginx, without docker and other services. How can I check how resources files are copied?

Comment: Well for start you can check the nlog config and figure that is it correct or not? sometimes the log service can not find the path you defined and make the program slower than normal.